# What species of tree is this (found in Navarre, Spain, many tiny flowers)?

Tags: species-identification, botany, trees

It was planted within the urban area of [Pamplona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pamplona), Navarre, in Spain. It does not seem like it's native to the area, since no trees like it are found in nearby forests. Its size is of 7-9 meters, while its leaves were commonly 4-5 cm long. It was spring when these photos were taken. It had a great number of tiny, dark flowers. It also showed tumor-like growths where the trunk begins to branch.

[image: Upper portion]

[image: Trunk]

[[image: Branch[5]]

[image: Flowers]

[image: Leaf]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking at Box Elder, *Acer negundo*.  It's a North American species but according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acer_negundo) it is naturalized in Europe.  If you search online for images, you will see the leaves and flower structures in your own pictures.  Specimens I have seen in my area (Indiana, USA) are very similar to your pictures, even identical, and the trunk is gnarly, as you observed.

Comment: Nice identification, +1. There's a picture [here](https://www.calfloranursery.com/plants/acer-negundo) if you want it.

Comment: Thanks. After Googleing it, it seems to be the male plant (landscapeplants.oregonstate.edu/plants/acer-negundo).

Comment: Interesting... I did not know or did not remember it is dioecous.